# Making posts searchable over the Internet

Tags: support, search-engine

I was just wondering if there is anything done to make posts appear on, say, Google search results. Most of the Stack Overflow posts I end up with from Google *have* answers. Is there anything done to those non-answered posts so that they don't appear in the search results?

Comment: What if they had the answers or the lack of all the way down the bottom of a really long page they have to scroll to get through? But not before a few subscription panels and ad boxes?

Comment: If you think that unanswered posts are *not* indexed by Google: they are.

Answer (score 2):

It's good news for the SO community if both answered and unanswered questions rank well on Google.

Answered questions help enhance the SO community reputation (for lack of a better word) and if someone within the SO community can't make a good enough answer, perhaps someone who's yet to join might know the answer - and if they stumble upon the question through Google where's the harm?